# Does my component need force update to scrollIntoView?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm making my first react + redux app and I have a question. I have a component that render a input field and, as some content is added above it, I need it to scrollIntoVIew.

So, I just added the scrollIntoView in the component componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("scroll");
    this.refs.input.scrollIntoView();
}
```

The only problem is that this component does not re render each time (as nothing change in it) so the scrollIntoVIew is called only one time.

I could force update to component but this is not really good practice isn't it ? What can I do in this case ?

Comment: Try force reflow with for example `this.refs.offsetTop`. https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: @Theo.T Can you explain your solution with a bit more details, I'm kind of lost

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your issue. However, what is it that is meant to trigger the scrollInToView? A property change, a user event?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `setState` and update some object in the component's state every time content is added to re-render the component, and `componentDidUpdate` will be invoked.
You could also use the second argument (callback) to `setState`, but the React docs say the following about second argument of `setState`:

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>   Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic
>   instead.

Comment: Yes of course, but I am looking for a cleaner way to do this

Comment: In this case, instead of using `componentDidUpdate` it's probably better  to use the `setState` callback (second argument) to invoke the method.

Comment: It is not recommended though. See my updated answer https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6320